# Visibility of a referenced class in WCF

Tags: wcf, callback

I will explain directly by the code :

```
AddObjectToDatabase()
{
     Publish(theMessage);
}
```

theMessage is an object of "Message" class.
AddObjectToDatabase is a service method.
"Publish" Method calls "CallBackMethod" of a IPublishing interface with a Message as parameter. Actually, it iterates through a `List<IPublishing>` static object (containing all the publishers) and for each one, call the CallBackMethod method.

In the projet calling the service, I do that :

```
Class TestClass : IPublishing
{
    ...
    TestMethod()
    {
        ...
        ISubscription subsriberProxy = ProxyCreator.createProxy(this);
        subsriberProxy.Subscribe("client1");
        theService.AddObjectToDatabase();
    }

    CallBackMethod(Message m)
    {
    }
}
```

The TestClass class must implement a Method named "CallBackMethod", with receive a Message object as parameter.

My problem here is that the service is added by "Service Reference" and the Message class is unknown by TestClass as it is not used directly in the service but into a method of the service.

When I just add a new method to the service with Message as parameter, then the service know that object and it works perfectly.
I can't change the architecture of the code as I have not coded this part.

Is there a way to "know" all the object used by the service, even those who are not used directly ?

**EDIT 1 :**
the callback is implemented via netTcpBinding.
I can't post a section because all the config is by code.

I tried to add `[KnownType(typeof(Message))]` in another DataContract (already known) and now I can see it in visual studio.
I also tried to change the callback method with (Object) instead of (Message), and tried this solution : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx

Now the "only" issue is a InvalidCastException. Indeed he could not cast from TheServiceClass.Message to TheClassLibrary.Message
TheServiceClass is the class used with the service reference (generated), TheClassLibrary is the class where the Message class is defined.

Comment: Is the callback implemented via wsDualHttpBinding?

Comment: how about posting your system.servicemodel section of your configuration here?  Also, is the Message class marked with a DataContract attribute?

Comment: see my Edit 1, I've figured out about something else...